# SSRS report model cardinality

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

In SSRS report models there is a drop down to set cardinalities of role relationships.  What's the difference between different cardinality options. 
For example what is mean by

- One
- Many
- Optional one
- Optional many

Please give an example that shows the table relation ships and how they are joined at the end in the report model.

Comment: [First Google result](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c47a401e-c704-4b4c-8bd0-c01cdaff8b26/report-model-rules-of-cardinality?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 0):

So fare the best explanation is found at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c47a401e-c704-4b4c-8bd0-c01cdaff8b26/report-model-rules-of-cardinality?forum=sqlreportingservices

However, going through an **actual implemetnation**, I don't see a case where we need Optional Many and Many. **Can someone explain how this will differs in the final rendering**.